# Read out of bounds error when using ilspy

Tags: c#, ilspy

[image]

When using Ilspy I am getting a `Read out of bounds` error:

`System.BadImageFormatException: Read out of bounds.在 System.Reflection.Throw.OutOfBounds() 在 System.Reflection.Metadata.BlobReader.ReadInt32()`

How should I address this?

Comment: Something about that assembly is invalid. Maybe the assembly you're trying to decompile is obfuscated?
You could report this as a bug in ILSpy; in theory the decompiler could handle this exception and at least report partial information for the affected method.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not a valid assembly or the architecture bitness is invalid (what is for decompiler most unlikly).